# How to center a pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to center a graph made with pgfplots with `\centering`. If I put `\centering` within a group to limit its scope, the graph does not get centered. If I don't limit the scope of `\centering`, then everything gets centered.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
This text should not be centered, but the graph should be.

% \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates { (0, 0) (1, 1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
% \endgroup

This text should not be centered.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you do not want to use a float (`figure`) here, which I would recommend, you should just wrap it in `\begin{center}\end{center}`

Comment: Note that `\begingroup` is plain TeX. You could use `{}` as well. The `\centering`-command needs a paragraph in order to see the end of its use. If you add a blank line in front of `\endgroup`, you will succeed as well.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi `\begingroup` is not necessarily Plain TeX. It's a primitive, but it's used everywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing special about `tikzpicture` here you would see the same with

```
{\centering X}
```

`\centering` works by setting the paragraph parameters, so if you close the group before the paragraph ends then nothing happens. You can use

```
{\centering
 X

 }
```

To centre an `X` (or a `tikzpicture`).
Or more naturally use

```
\begin{center}
X
\end{center}
```

which also adds some vertical space.